# Bio line beneath pp in BuddyPress?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, buddypress

I’m new to BP and WP! I have a quick question:

How can I show a one-line bio beneath usernames in the list of members in the ‘Members’ page of my BuddyPress website? For example, Facebook has a similar feature; it shows a name with a description beneath, e.g. ‘John Smith’ with ‘Engineer at Nuts & Bolts Co’ right beneath it.

I found the following line of code in member-header.php:
`<h2 class=”user-nicename”>@<?php bp_displayed_user_username(); ?></h2>1`

I thought about adding another line beneath for the bio field, but I’m not sure what to replace “bp_displayed_user_username();” with – I don’t think there is a “bp_displayed_user_bio();”. Should I create it? If so, how?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'member-header.php' is for single member pages. 
If you want the bio to display on singe member pages, create a [template overload](http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/#overloading-template-compatibility-theme-files).

Then add this:

```
<?php
    $bio = xprofile_get_field_data('Bio'); 
    //If the field is not called Bio, then change it above

    if( !empty( $bio ) 
        echo 'Bio: ' . $bio; 

?>
```

If you want Bio to display on the members page that shows all members, then create a template overload of this page: 
\buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\members-loop.php

And look for this: `bp_member_profile_data( 'field=the field name' );`
Uncomment it and change to to, for example, `bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Bio' );`